# Getting maven Build Error: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded in ~/.m2/settings-security.xml

Tags: java, maven

As per the [document](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html), I have created/added following code in my ~/.m2/settings-security.xml file:

```
<settingsSecurity>
    <master>{ENCRIPTED_PASSWORD}</master>
</settingsSecurity>
```

After taking maven build(mvn clean package), getting following error:

```
[ERROR] error using security dispatcher: org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.PlexusCipherException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecDispatcherException: org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.PlexusCipherException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded


[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jarsigner-plugin:1.4:sign (sign) on project com.daimler.duke.common.server: error using security dispatcher: org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.PlexusCipherException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]
```

http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Can any on pleas help me on this I'm new with the maven now.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you have password (or encripted password) with some "bad" symbols? Like '$', '!', '+', '{' or '}'. Look at the [tips](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html#Tips).

Comment: After removing the '{,}' i got Error: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jarsigner-plugin:1.4:sign (sign) on project com.daimler.duke.common.server: Failed executing 'cmd.exe /X /C "C:\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\..\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore ../DukeUpdateSite/resources/DUKE.jks -storepass ***** -keypass ***** C:\Workspace\Trunk\com.daimler.duke.common.server\target\com.daimler.duke.common.server-182.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar duke"' - exitcode 1 -> [Help 1]`

Comment: try to escaping. Example from tips: `jSMOWnoPFgsHVpMvz5VrIt5kRbzGpI8u+{EF1iFQyJQ=` turns into `{jSMOWnoPFgsHVpMvz5VrIt5kRbzGpI8u+\{EF1iFQyJQ=}` - in curly braces and with \{

Comment: My password not contains any "{" symbols in middle, for eg my password is : `{wkjfheiofho+klafjj}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to regenerate the password. Editing a generated password may corrupt it.

Below is the sample command to generate it. Please note use quotes around your password while generating it using mvn command.

```
mvn -emp "<PASSWORD>" and mvn -ep "<PASSWORD>"
```

Comment: How can i avoid to add my master password in ~/.m2/settings-security.xml?

Comment: You cannot avoid that. But I will suggest you keep your settings-security.xml file at remote location and access it in your ~./m2/settings-security.xml.

You can provide the location like below

      <settingsSecurity>
        <relocation>/Volumes/usb-key/settings-security.xml</relocation>
      </settingsSecurity>